# Sorting list of strings by their length and the last N characters

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I'm trying to solve a problem, where I have to sort a list of strings by the length of the string as well as the last characters in the string. In the case of the string having the same length and same last character, they should be sorted by second to last character and so on.

I have this code, but I'm not clear on why it does not work as I intend. Could someone point me in the right direction?

My code:

```
import sys

word_lists = [line.split(' ') for line in ' '.join([x.strip() for x in sys.stdin.readlines()]).split('  ')]
for i in range(0, len(word_lists)):
    word_lists[i] = sorted((word_lists[i]), key=lambda x: (x[:-1], len(x)))
```

Input:

```
apple
banana
grape
kiwi
pear

airplane
bicycle
boat
car
```

Output:

```
[['apple', 'banana', 'grape', 'kiwi', 'pear'], ['airplane', 'bicycle', 'boat', 'car']]
```

Expected Output:

```
[['banana', 'apple', 'grape', 'kiwi', 'pear'], ['bicycle', 'airplane', 'car', 'boat']]
```

Comment: It looks like you want to compare reversed strings. It isn't quite clear how exactly the lenghs should be taken into account (depends on what "as well as" means in your book). Presumably you need to use the length as the primary key and the reversed string as the tie breaker. If so, why do you want bicycle before airplane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `x[::-1]`.

**Ex:**

```
l = [['apple', 'banana', 'grape', 'kiwi', 'pear'], ['airplane', 'bicycle', 'boat', 'car']]
for i in l:
    print(sorted(i, key=lambda x: (x[::-1], len(x))))
```

**Output:**

```
['banana', 'apple', 'grape', 'kiwi', 'pear']
['bicycle', 'airplane', 'car', 'boat']
```

---

```
output = [sorted(i, key=lambda x: (x[::-1], len(x))) for i in l]
print(output)
--> [['banana', 'apple', 'grape', 'kiwi', 'pear'], ['bicycle', 'airplane', 'car', 'boat']]
```

Comment: `x[::-1]` instead of `x[-1]` to deal with ties, rather than just the last character

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It might have been a bad example from my side. But in case of to strings having same length and also ending on the same letter this method seems to give me wrong outputs once in a while (i tested earlier). Say the two last words in the second list was `'car'` and `'cer'` then `car` should come before cer as e is before a. Hope it made sense..

Comment: Looks like @sacul wrote answer to my comment while i wrote it. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to data first sort on length of string so you must change keys orders in your code and also you want your string sort in alphabetical order from tail so you must send characters from tail (x[::-1]) so finally you must change your key by
key(len(x), x[::-1])